# iOS @protocol as a way of "marking" the ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

In my app I need to make some changes to BarButtonItems in a UINavigationBar every time a new ViewController is pushed on the stack. I do it in the UINavigationController delegate method

```
-navigationController: willShowViewController: animated:
```

But there are some exceptions. I needed a way to "mark" a couple of ViewController that did not need these changes. It's a pain to look for them in the navigation stack. So I couldn't think of anything better than declare a protocol with no methods and use it as a "marker". If I don't want changes, my ViewController needs to conform to this protocol.

```
if ([viewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CustomMarker)]) {
    //don't do my stuff
} else {
    //do my stuff
}
```

Is this a good way of achieving my goal? Is there a better known practice?

Comment: What is the 'stuff'? Will there be more special cases in the future? Would those special cases need some info from the view controllers?

Comment: I think I'd be inclined to add a method to the view controllers, something like `- (BOOL)requiresBarButtonModification`.  You could add this method to a sub-class of UIViewController with a default of `YES` and then override the method in the  VC exceptions to return `NO`.

Comment: "stuff" stands for changing back button to a custom button. I can't think of a case where I need info from viewController besdies the fact that it does or doesn't needs this custom button.

Comment: @mttrb thats exactly what I did in the first place, but protocol seems like an easier to implement solution. I didn't mention that I have already done this protocol thing and it works perfectly. I just wanted to know if there is a better way or am I going to face any known problems with my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, Protocols are great technique to communicate between objects,
Here is an example how I'm using that

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    // If destination is NewsAcceptor than sending news data
    if ([segue.destinationViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(AFMagnoliaNodeAcceptor)]) {
        [(id<AFMagnoliaNodeAcceptor>)segue.destinationViewController setNode:sender];
    }
   ..... Other stuff
}
```

And this code is written in Base - ViewController, so if I want to pass node object between viewControllers then I'm marking my viewControlelr with protocol `AFMagnoliaNodeAcceptor`, so the object is automatically passed to there.

Comment: for sending messages, it's better to check if the object responds to the selector using `respondsToSelector:`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use isKindOfClass instead of protocol:

```
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]])
```

just replace MyViewController with the class you want to test it against.

But as @Wain said if there are going to be loads of view controllers you want to test it's easer to use protocols because you will use just one if statement.

In my solution you have to test every view controller.

Comment: That was the first idea that came to my mind. But in that way I have to subclass all of my "exceptions" from custom UIViewController subclass, not generic UIViewController, seems like one more step than what I did with protocol. Is there a benefit to using isKindOfClass compared to conformsToProtocol?